# Error with restoring from a split .bak file with password

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup, restore, errors, password

I am trying to restore a backup from a split .bak file[.bak_1/.bak_2/.bak_3]. The backup is password protected. So far this is what I have and I cannot seem to format in a way that does not throw me an error.

```
USE master
GO
RESTORE DATABASE client_a_database1
  FROM DISK = 'G:\database1\***.bak_1',
       DISK = 'G:\database1\***.bak_2',
       DISK = 'G:\database1\***.bak_3'
  WITH MOVE 'database1_data' TO 'G:\database1\***.mdf'
       MOVE 'database1_log' TO 'G:\database1\***.ldf', REPLACE,
  Password 'password'
  GO
```

With this format I am getting an error on the Password that I have added.

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't it MEDIAPASSWORD in stead of PASSWORD?

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: Error reads - INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR 'GO'. Expecting 'TO'

Comment: I have tried different formats and layouts - however always seem to get an error.

Comment: Can you post the output of `RESTORE HEADERONLY` ? Also there should be `password = 'password'`. You have not put the `=`.

Comment: @EdwardDortland its the other way Password is correct.

Comment: Well the real error message would help a lot. Please copy & paste the complete error message.

Comment: Thank you @Kin that was what was needed, just an '=' sign - unfortunaltly now it is stating the restore was taken from a different MS SQL version. All this for little gain.

Comment: @Kin - Being quite new to MS SQL I would of had to take a bit of time to research doing the `RESTORE HEADERONLY` task. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below will work, as you had syntax error :

```
USE master
GO
RESTORE DATABASE client_a_database1
  FROM DISK = 'G:\database1\***.bak_1',
       DISK = 'G:\database1\***.bak_2',
       DISK = 'G:\database1\***.bak_3'
  WITH MOVE 'database1_data' TO 'G:\database1\***.mdf'
       MOVE 'database1_log' TO 'G:\database1\***.ldf', REPLACE,
  Password = 'password'
  GO
```

Also, a RESTORE HEADERONLY output will help understand why you are getting -

> restore was taken from a different MS SQL version.